# Handling undefined values in 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Its basically an out of bounds check, tho' I'm having issues understanding how to deal with `undefined` values in a 2d array.

What I've tried so far is checking if both the column and the row index exist `if(!arr[x][y])`, checking if both are undefined `if(arr[x][y] === undefined)` and finally checking if the indexes are bigger then the array length - 1 ( the array is 10x10 ).

None of the above have worked, even when putting the conditions togheter I still get

`TypeError: Cannot set property '' of undefined`.

Is there a way to deal with this ?

Edit:

The `TypeError` appears at `if (arr[x + i * dx][y + i * dy] === undefined)` more precisely at `[y + i * dy]` where `x` and `y` are the column and row indexes, `dx` and `dy` are either 0 or 1 values so it can check either vertically or horizontally.

If I check vertically, I dont get any errors, its only when I check horizontally that I encounter the `TypeError`.

Comment: That's not how 2D arrays work. They're basically just arrays of arrays: arr[x][y] is (arr[x])[y].

Comment: Can you show us how you define (or fill) `arr`?

Comment: @DenysSéguret My mistake.

Comment: @TudorApostol, please edit your question, and put that code there.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir https://jsbin.com/vuduvuvimu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Tudor Apostol, please provide a [Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  It can be difficult to assist without having the code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @TudorApostol, in the jsbin code you did not define `obj` anywhere.  But please add the code *that produces the error* in your question, not in jsbin. Indent code using the `{ }` tool in the toolbar you get when you edit your question.

Comment: The error: `TypeError: Cannot set property '' of undefined` is caused because `x < 0 || x > 9` (or not even a number) or because one of the subarrays don't exist (probably removed).

Comment: + you should split the check `arr[x][y]` to `arr[x] && arr[x][y]` to be safe.

Comment: @trincot Hope the edit helps.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, the subarrays is where I'm facing this issue. How can I approach solving this issue ?

Comment: You can check if the subscript are valid before accessing the element from the 2D array: `if (x + i * dx < 0 || 9 < x + i * dx || y + i * dy < 0 || 9 < y + i * dy || arr[x + i * dx][y + i * dy] === undefined) { /* Either the subscripts are invalid or the cell at (x + i * dx, y + i * dy) is not defined */ }`.

Comment: ... Itstill vague though. What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Basically I'm randomizing values for both x and y so I can get a random arr[x][y] index and I want to check for `i` amount of neighboring indexes both on the right and on the bottom of the randomized initial index.

Comment: @TudorApostol, please post code with which we can reproduce the problem. The error you get would not occur if the values of x, y, dx, dy are as you say, so there must be something going wrong. We can only see what, if you provide enough code for us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check like this instead:

```
if (arr[x + i * dx] === undefined || arr[x + i * dx][y + i * dy] === undefined)
```

This way, if the row is undefined, the second check is not performed and won't throw an error. This is possible thanks to shirt-circuit evaluation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation